# ways to modify existing php script so that it echoes smaller versions of images,

Tags: php, resources, image-compression

I have a script on my site that displays any image files I add to a certain folder. I use this folder as a depository for any digital art I make. That way I can just save png's from Photoshop or whatever directly to that folder and the will display on the page.

The problem is that the files sizes are too large to be loaded easily, even if they are displaying correctly. The .css class is the image resizer.

Can you resize an image without loading it entirely? I might be understanding this wrong, thanks for your help.

```
<?php
    $dir = "../endlessdescriptionone/images/";
    $dh = opendir($dir);
    $gallery = array();
    while($filename = readdir($dh)) {
        $filepath = $dir.$filename;

        //pregmatch usedto be ereg
        if (is_file($filepath) and preg_match("/\.png$/",$filename)) {
            $gallery[] = $filepath;
        }
    }
    sort($gallery);

    foreach($gallery as $image) {
        echo"<img src='$image' class='resizesmall'>";
    }
?>
```

Comment: You could create a script that generates thumbnails on the fly.

Comment: this posted script would be much simpler using scandir()

Answer (score 2):

Check out phpthumb, it's pretty much the de-facto thumbnail generator and offers automated caching to improve speed after the first load. At a very basic level all you have to do is point the image source tag at the phpthumb script with the required width, height and file location in the GET string.

Due to phpthumb's license, i also had to create my own simple thumbnailer for the odd occasion. If you know your way around the PHP doc's site, you could throw together your own thumbnailer in under a few hours and learn something in the process.

Failing all that, you could do it the manual way and upload two copies of your image, one large, and one resized and only have it display the resized ones (i.e. only ones that contain "_thumb" in the filename).

Comment: for reasons of convenience I'd like to keep the original files in their original, large size. Would phpthumb still give me the massive performance hit inherent with these large images?

Comment: yes, phpthumb simply generates a second file with the image resized and serves that to the browser instead of the original larger image. If you configure it properly, you can tell it to cache the thumbnails so next time a user requests the large image, instead of generating a smaller image first, it looks in the cache folder and serves the cached smaller image giving a very large performance boost

Comment: do you have a definitive link for phpthumb? there seem to be at least two. http://phpthumb.gxdlabs.com/ is probably it...

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot use CSS to reduce the actual resolution of the image that is loaded by the browser.

What you could do is have a another script that is used inside the img src tag that loads the image and resizes before outputting it.

Answer (score 1):

The common use is to display thumbnails (samples) of big images, and then, when selected: download or view.

You can create the thumbnail directly from photoshop.